# Override onActivityResult makes the build fail

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

According to [react-native-fbsdk documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current), I have to override the `onActivityResult()` method by adding this in my MainApplication:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

If I add those lines to my file, Android studio throw me an error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDev19DebugJavaWithJavac'
```

Am I adding this lines in a wrong file / wrong way?

Here's the [MainApplication.java](https://gist.github.com/poptocrack/5232cf9d65e7f6b962ea40e6f5e42e66) I have at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the onActivityResult() to your (Main)Activity, not to the Application object.